# django Mongo-db automatic failover from Primary(master) to Secondary(slave)

Tags: django, mongodb

I've developed a web-app in django, and have used MongoDB for backend.
I'm not sure how to do an automatic failover for the database.
My requirement is that, suppose when Primary node of mongodb is down, django should automatically connect to Secondary node.

How can this be achieved?
I found this library, https://github.com/brianjaystanley/django-failover
which is for django 1.3, but i want for django 1.5

What settings do i need to change, or any library available for the rescue? Any solutions on the floor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to set up anything in your you application to handle this and the link you provided for the library is not appropriate for use with MongoDB as it is a relational back end solution.

The first case here is do you actually have a [**Replica Set**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/) Configuration for MongoDB? I can only answer presuming that you but the link is worthwhile reading as from your question you probably do not have a core understanding of MongoDB Replication concepts.

What will be explained there is that there is no Secondary for your application to failover to, what actually happens is the Replica Set itself elects amongst it's members which node will become the Primary.

Going on with the answer, you configure your application to handle the failover through settting up your [**Connection String**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) to the driver. Read through that documentation and you will find that among other useful things, you are basically providing a list of hostnames which will be members of the Replica Set. You don't need all the members, but just enough to be a seed list so that the other nodes can be discovered. That would just happen anyway with the correct options, but it is good practice to have more than one host to contact even to get that information. Here's a sample:

```
mongodb://<Primary>,<Secondary>/<database>
```

You may possibly want to take a look at [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/), considering you probably have experience with django and it uses modelling concepts that you will be familiar with, whilst still allowing access to MongoDB features. There is some documentation there on setting up Replica Set connections from memory.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
 Yes I do have a replica set in place. 1 Primary, 1 Secondary, 1 Arbiter. In pymongo, its fine when i give a connection string to discover one of the modes. But the issue is with django actually. In django's settings.py, where i have given connection strings (URI of 3 nodes), if the primary fails, it is not moving over to the other node automatically.

Comment: Your issue may well be with how you have the connection set up. Follow the link for Connection String in the answer for the details. Not sure but what you have set up is probably not what you need. You should have **One** connection string that has Both your Primary and Secondary node hostnames in it, the Arbiter will not help here as was described in the answer. It sounds to be like you have these "individually" defined in a manner that would be used for implementation of some relational failover. That is not what you want. You want only one connection as described.